# Conditional validation using primefaces in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two entities in JSF that are dropdowns. If i am selelcting month then i should compulsarily select year. If i have not selected Year and only selected month then a validation error should appear on click of submit button. Is such form of conditional validation possible in primefaces. I had tried javascript method but i failed somehow. How can it be acheived using primefaces.?
Below are my two entities.

```
<p:outputLabel for="year" value="Year: " /> 
            <p:selectOneMenu id="year" style="width:150px   " value="#{bean.year}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="All"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2014" itemValue="2014"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2013" itemValue="2013"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2012" itemValue="2012"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2011" itemValue="2011"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2010" itemValue="2010"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2009" itemValue="2009"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel for="month" value="Month: " />                   
            <p:selectOneMenu id="month" style="width:150px" value="#{bean.month}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="All"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="January" itemValue="01"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="February" itemValue="02"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="March" itemValue="03"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="April" itemValue="04"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="May" itemValue="05"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="June" itemValue="06"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="July" itemValue="07"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="August" itemValue="08"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="September" itemValue="09"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="October" itemValue="10"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="November" itemValue="11"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="December" itemValue="12"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute **required="true"** to your selectOneMenu of year

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="year" style="width:150px" required="true" value="#{bean.year}">
           <!-- some code here -->
   </p:selectOneMenu>
   <p:message for="year" display="icon" />
```

note that the tag message is for showing where the error has happened .for the selectOneMenu of month do the same thing ..

Comment: i need a custom validation, if i have selected month and not selected year then the validation should get performed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this simple solution for your case, and if you want to use Custom validator, you have to follow steps:

1. Create a validator class by implementing the
   `javax.faces.validator.Validator` interface.
2. Override `validate()` method.
3. Assign an unique validator ID via `@FacesValidator` annotation.
4. Reference custom validator class to JSF component via f:validator
   tag.

You can go [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/) for more information Custom validator in JSF 2.0